# Why my cv::Mat become grey color?

Tags: ios, opencv, avcapturesession

Here is how I implement the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`:

```
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    OSType format = CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(pixelBuffer);
    CGRect videoRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer),     CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer));
    AVCaptureVideoOrientation videoOrientation = [[[_captureOutput connections] objectAtIndex:0] videoOrientation];

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
    void *baseaddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);

    cv::Mat my_mat = cv::Mat(videoRect.size.height, videoRect.size.width, NULL, baseaddress, 0); //<<<<----HERE
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
```

Here is how I set the capture format the format:

```
    OSType format = kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA;

// Check YUV format is available before selecting it (iPhone 3 does not support it)
if ([_captureOutput.availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes containsObject:
     [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange]]) {
    format = kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange;
}

_captureOutput.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:format]
                                                           forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
```

Comment: I think you need to pass a data type for cv::Matcv::Mat constructor (the third parameter I guess, why is it NULL?)...

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens because of `NULL` passed as 3rd parameter. It should be `CV_8UC4` for 4-channel image:

```
cv::Mat my_mat = cv::Mat(videoRect.size.height, videoRect.size.width, CV_8UC4, baseaddress);
```